# Up to date dom source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, firebug

I am doing a webpage with some javascript and I change several elements in the dom.
Anyway I am not able with chrome nor with firefox (and firebug) to **see the up to date dom source code** (of course the rendering in the browser is fine).

Namely, if I add some stuff in my page (let's say a list) with the javascript, I can see the list appearing in my browser but not in the source code with any of the tools I have.

Is there any tool to do that?

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: In Chrome, I believe you want "Inspect Element" rather than "View Source"

Comment: should be fine in firebug. Try using the 'inspect element', click in the new element and it should show you the thing

Comment: The inspect element directly in the page not in the DOM view solved it. Thx @mwilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, you can add the Web Developer Extension: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Within it, there is a View Generated Source action. It allows you to see the source after DOM additions via Javascript.

Although, you should be able to view the changes in Firebug and the Chrome Consoles

Comment: Where do you find it, I searched on google and couldn't find it.

Comment: I linked it in my answer. I suspect you've seen that by now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that makes sense. HTML added by JavaScript will not necessarily show when viewing source, but developer tools like Firebug and Chrome's Developer Tools should allow you to see it.

If you're worried about it not showing up because of Search Engine Optimization stuff, adding JS isn't the way to add the content, as search engine bots will not see the JS-generated content.

Comment: Sure I know about the search-engine stuff, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

When you do a view source you don't see the updated DOM. you can see updated DOM with tools like firebug, did you try firebug? its a firefox add-in..

Comment: you don't do anything, it automatically gets updated when firebug is running... if you want to see the HTML of your new created elements, you can right click and select inspect element..